# Powershell Write-Progress Duplicating Entry and adding a Time for executing the entry

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have very basic skills in programming. I have a PowerShell script for Microsoft Teams that looks at a list of Users in a .csv file and returns a few properties of the user, then exports it to another .csv with the results. This works fine. What I'm trying to do is add a progress bar with the time that it takes at the end for each line to execute. When the progress bar completes, it does not end but stays on the last entry and it duplicated it. Please see the picture of what I'm referring to. I don't know the code to add the time it takes to execute each of the .csv at the end. (purple circle in the picture is an example of what i want to do)

```
Write-host "Connecting to Microsoft Teams....." -ForegroundColor Yellow
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
Write-host "Successfully connected to Microsoft Teams" -ForegroundColor Green

$CsvFilePath = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Users\Desktop\MicrosoftTeams\precheckbatch2.csv" 
$Count=0

$results = foreach ($UPN in $CsvFilePath) {   
$user = $UPN.UserPrincipalName 
Get-CsOnlineUser $user | Select-Object Displ*, UserPri*, IsSipEnabled, TeamsUpgradeE*, 
Enterprise*, @{l="FeatureTypes";e={$_.FeatureTypes -join "; "}}, @{l="AssignedPlan";e= 
{$_.AssignedPlan -join "; "}}

Write-Progress -Activity "`n Processing User: $Count" "Currently Processing: $user"
$Count++
}

$results | Export-Csv C:\Users\Desktop\MicrosoftTeams\precheckdataresults1.csv
Write-host "`nDone!"
```

[image: Progress Bar Error]

Comment: Presumably the newline (`\`n` ) character interferes with the [`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress) cmdlet. What about: `Write-Host; Write-Progress -Activity " Processing User: $Count" "Currently Processing: $user"`?

Comment: Excellent! Thanks, @iRon. that worked. completely missed that. Would you happen to know how to add a time for how long it took each entry in the CSV to run.

Comment: The easiest way would be to add the time to the status text of the progress bar, once the current operation has finished. To add it on the right side of the progressbar, you'd have to tinker with the current cursor position, which is somewhat brittle.

Comment: Thank you kindly, I will explore that. Much appreciated

Comment: Hi Guys, The Above solution works except for how you end the write progress bar.  
After I get the Done!, Its stil shows the last entry until I hit enter then it disappears.

Connecting to Microsoft Teams.....
Done!
PS C:\Users\Desktop\MicrosoftTeams>
Processing User: 8 [Currently Processing: abc@abcmail.com ]